# Adding margin to sections breaks the three column design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, multiple-columns, padding

Below are the HTML & CSS code for a simple three-column design. But when I add `padding: 0 1%;`, it breaks the column and pushes the third column to the second row. It's really weird because I thought I added padding, which should be inside the div, as opposed to margin? How do I fix that?

```css
#container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
  width: 100%
}

.part {
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 0 1%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="part"><img>
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="part"><img>
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="part"><img>
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="part"><img>
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="part"><img>
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="part"><img>
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="part"><img>
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="part"><img>
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="part"><img>
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add box-sizing: border-box in #container. It will include padding and border in the element's total width and height

Comment: @HienLuong not to #container, but to `.part` however this might causes issues in IE due to the percentage width and padding.

Comment: Also - divs are block elements - make them `inline-block`

Comment: have you considered using bootstrap? you're reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: @fnostro that won't work with the given html since there are spaces between the divs

Comment: If you are having trouble with IE and border box then just put a wrapper inside of `.part` and add the padding in there instead of `.part`. You can also remove the with 100% for row, it's display block and auto width is 100%

Comment: Just add float: left into row and part. It should work fine for the issue in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First side note: you're missing `display: inline-block` from `part` div.

> I added padding, which should be inside the div, as opposed to margin

No, padding isn't inside the div by default, the padding is added to the actual width so that the full width of each part will be:

33% + 1% padding from left + 1% right padding = 35%;

and the total width of row will be: 105%, so it wan't fit in the container and will split to another row.

One solution is to `part` width: 31%;

```css
  #container {
      width: 800px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .row {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .part {
      width: 31%;
      padding: 0 1%;
      display: inline-block
    }
```

```html
 <div id="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

other solution if you want to consider all the padding as part of width is to use:

```
* {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

```css
  * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
  
  #container {
      width: 800px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .row {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .part {
      width: 33%;
      padding: 0 1%;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

**Third Solution and the best in my opinion** is to use `display: grid` to each row;

```css
 #container {
      width: 800px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .row {
      width: 100%;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
    .part {
      padding: 0 1%;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="part">
          <img />
          <p class="text">some text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: There are other ways to do this but this is a feasible solution, no harm to include both solutions. Also, test this out on IE, it's possible it might bug out

Comment: welcome, I've updated answer with three valid solutions

Answer (score 0):

Because box-sizing does not inherit to children use

```
#container, #container * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Try to avoid horizontal margin in responsive websites because box-sizing excludes the margin.

Comment: Adding border-box to #container will avooid the div to expand greater then 800px when giving this div a padding or border.

Comment: I know what the rule does but container has no padding

Comment: It's good practice to use border-box as default setting on **all** elements in all styles to prevent things as asked in your question. Default like this: `* { box-sizing: border-box; }`

Comment: Maybe for a new site but definitely not an already developed site. Also you might as well apply `*{...}` then

Answer (score 0):

After I have test your code, for my opinion to add box-sizing: border-box at universal selector "*" 
or you can follow this rule without box-sizing.

```
.part {width: calc(33.33% - 3%); /* 3% mean part+part+part padding. */ padding: 0 1%;display: inline-block; /* you can also use float: left or inline-block */ }
```

Thanks.